# Javascript: strange comparison behaviour

Tags: javascript

If I execute the following snippet in FireBug console it somehow prints `surprise!`:

```
['surprise!', 'boring'][Number(0=="​")]
```

But why?

**UPD**

I am sorry, people, that was a joke! Jere is the first who noticed! Yesterday I found a [ZERO WIDTH SPACE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-width_space) in a string, and had since then temptation to have some fun =)

Comment: @micha, mind the `==`, not the `===`

Comment: No, his firebug recognizes mistakes and fixes them.

Comment: I feel ashamed for participating... at least I guess we learned something minor

Comment: @Jere, I am sorry, I do not think you were so much hurt. Now at least you know where to find during debugging

Comment: True. How did you run into the zero width space in the first place?

Comment: Great question! Voting up! :-)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is an extra, non visible, character between **your quotes**.

If you type this out, you will get 'boring' because 0=="" evaluates to true, Number(true) evalutes to 1.

Paste these two and watch the differing output:

```
0=="​"
```

outputs **false**

```
0==""
```

outputs **true**

The only thing I have changed is deleting the character between `""`.

Comment: Yes, Jere is right. Copy and paste line somethere, then move with keyboard arrow and you'll notice one extra stop. It might be very tiny space

Comment: I initially was going to type up the same answer as everbody else... but noticed the black magic. :)

Comment: Nice spot. I did think it was wrong when I pasted it into chrome console and it returned 0. Never twigged though :(

Answer (score 9):

`0=="​"` is `false` (**Because you have a non-printing character in the string**), `Number(false)` is `0` (as per [page 34 of the spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-262.pdf)), and "surprise" is the 0th index of the array.

Answer (score 4):

[ES5 11.9.3 The `==` operator](http://es5.github.com/#x11.9.3)

> If Type(x) is Number and Type(y) is String,
>   return the result of the comparison x == ToNumber(y).

and

> The MV of StringNumericLiteral ::: [empty] is 0.

So `0==""` returns `0 == ToNumber("")` which is `0 == 0` which is true.

By the `==` conversion rules `0==""` is `true`

[ES5 15.7.1.1 Number ( value )](http://es5.github.com/#x15.7.1.1) invokes [ES5 9.3 toNumber](http://es5.github.com/#x9.3) `toNumber(true) === 1`

And `["suprize!", "boring"][1]` returns `"boring"` which is clearly incorrect.

Why is it correct? Because

`"​".charCodeAt(0) === 8203`

Your string literal is not the empty string. You have a [zero width space](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/200b/index.htm) in your string.

Now if we go back to [ES5 11.9.3 `==` operator](http://es5.github.com/#x11.9.3) we see

> If the grammar cannot interpret the String as an expansion of StringNumericLiteral

Which means

- `0==""`
- `0==NaN`
- `false`
- `toNumber(false) === 0`
- `Number(0=="") === 0`
- `["suprize!", "boring"][0] === "suprize!"`

Answer (score 1):

`['surprise!', 'boring'][Number(0=="​")]` will return 'boring' becouse your code:

```
Number(0=="​") //returns true
```

But your code is diferent, you have an invisible char in your text, that's why is returning false.

If you write the code correctly will return true and the result will be `boring` as expected.

But if copy and paste your code, will return false, that's why you have a char between the "​" (you can check using keyboard or "​".length)

so your code will return false, that will be 0 then return 'surprise!'

You are cheating man :P

```
['surprise!', 'boring'][Number(0=="​")]

"​".length //returns 1 ;)

"​" != "" // OH GOD THIS IS TRUE :P
```

Answer (score 0):

I get boring when ran this in console
console.log(['surpeise!','boring'][Number(0=="")])