# Strip spaces/tabs/newlines - python

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, strip

I am trying to remove all spaces/tabs/newlines in python 2.7 on Linux.

I wrote this, that should do the job:

```
myString="I want to Remove all white \t spaces, new lines \n and tabs \t"
myString = myString.strip(' \n\t')
print myString
```

output:

```
I want to Remove all white   spaces, new lines 
 and tabs
```

It seems like a simple thing to do, yet I am missing here something. Should I be importing something?

Comment: Check out the answer to this related question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1185524/how-to-trim-whitespace-including-tabs strip() removes only leading and trailing characters, not ALL characters.

Comment: might be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8928557/python-splitting-string-by-all-space-characters

Comment: This worked for me, from the: [How to trim whitespace (including tabs)?][1]
    s = s.strip(' \t\n\r')


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1185524/how-to-trim-whitespace-including-tabs

Answer (score 179):

Use `str.split([sep[, maxsplit]])` with no `sep` or `sep=None`:

From [docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split):

> If `sep` is not specified or is `None`, a different splitting algorithm is
>   applied: runs of consecutive whitespace are regarded as a single
>   separator, and the result will contain no empty strings at the start
>   or end if the string has leading or trailing whitespace.

**Demo:**

```
>>> myString.split()
['I', 'want', 'to', 'Remove', 'all', 'white', 'spaces,', 'new', 'lines', 'and', 'tabs']
```

Use `str.join` on the returned list to get this output:

```
>>> ' '.join(myString.split())
'I want to Remove all white spaces, new lines and tabs'
```

Answer (score 82):

If you want to remove multiple whitespace items and replace them with single spaces, the easiest way is with a regexp like this:

```
>>> import re
>>> myString="I want to Remove all white \t spaces, new lines \n and tabs \t"
>>> re.sub('\s+',' ',myString)
'I want to Remove all white spaces, new lines and tabs '
```

You can then remove the trailing space with `.strip()` if you want to.

Comment: This is the cleanest solution

Answer (score 23):

Use the **re** library

```
import re
myString = "I want to Remove all white \t spaces, new lines \n and tabs \t"
myString = re.sub(r"[\n\t\s]*", "", myString)
print myString
```

**Output:**

> IwanttoRemoveallwhitespaces,newlinesandtabs

Comment: This is a correction of the original answer given by @TheGr8Adakron, not a duplicate

Comment: This does not preserve the spaces between the words rending the text useless for NLP.

Answer (score 13):

> **This will only remove the tab, newlines, spaces and nothing else.**

```
import re
myString = "I want to Remove all white \t spaces, new lines \n and tabs \t"
output   = re.sub(r"[\n\t\s]*", "", myString)
```

***OUTPUT:***

> IwantoRemoveallwhiespaces,newlinesandtabs

Good day!

Comment: Thanks for the solution - I think a minor correction is needed, it should be '+' instead of '*'.

Answer (score 12):

```
import re

mystr = "I want to Remove all white \t spaces, new lines \n and tabs \t"
print re.sub(r"\W", "", mystr)

Output : IwanttoRemoveallwhitespacesnewlinesandtabs
```

Comment: this also removes ';'

Answer (score 10):

The above solutions suggesting the use of regex aren't ideal because this is such a small task and regex requires more resource overhead than the simplicity of the task justifies.

Here's what I do:

`myString = myString.replace(' ', '').replace('\t', '').replace('\n', '')`

or if you had a bunch of things to remove such that a single line solution would be gratuitously long:

```
removal_list = [' ', '\t', '\n']
for s in removal_list:
  myString = myString.replace(s, '')
```

Comment: Arguably this solution is the most readable and memorable.

Answer (score 3):

How about a one-liner using a list comprehension within join?

```
>>> foobar = "aaa bbb\t\t\tccc\nddd"
>>> print(foobar)
aaa bbb                 ccc
ddd

>>> print(''.join([c for c in foobar if c not in [' ', '\t', '\n']]))
aaabbbcccddd
```

Answer (score 2):

Since there is not anything else that was more intricate, I wanted to share this as it helped me out.

This is what I originally used:

```python
import requests
import re

url = 'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10711116/strip-spaces-tabs-newlines-python' # noqa
headers = {'user-agent': 'my-app/0.0.1'}
r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
print("{}".format(r.content))
```

Undesired Result:

```html
b'<!DOCTYPE html>\r\n\r\n\r\n    <html itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/QAPage" class="html__responsive">\r\n\r\n    <head>\r\n\r\n        <title>string - Strip spaces/tabs/newlines - python - Stack Overflow</title>\r\n        <link
```

This is what I changed it to:

```python
import requests
import re

url = 'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10711116/strip-spaces-tabs-newlines-python' # noqa
headers = {'user-agent': 'my-app/0.0.1'}
r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
regex = r'\s+'
print("CNT: {}".format(re.sub(regex, " ", r.content.decode('utf-8'))))
```

Desired Result:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html> <html itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/QAPage" class="html__responsive"> <head> <title>string - Strip spaces/tabs/newlines - python - Stack Overflow</title>
```

The precise regex that @MattH had mentioned, was what worked for me in fitting it into my code.  Thanks!

Note: This is `python3`