# Strip tabs only at the end of line?

Tags: python, tabs, split

I have a huge text file, each line has a tab-delimited string. I need to keep all tabs apart from those at the end of each line. I need to keep the carriage return. Any ideas?

I've tried everything on these answers:

- [How to trim whitespace (including tabs)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1185524/how-to-trim-whitespace-including-tabs)
- [Trimming a string in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/761804/trimming-a-string-in-python)
- [Strip spaces/tabs/newlines - python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10711116/strip-spaces-tabs-newlines-python)

as well as others I've now closed the tabs on.

Comment: So where's your code, and what exactly is the problem with it? We don't do *"urgent"* here; this isn't a helpdesk. Also, are you sure removing the tabs isn't going to cause you problems when you later parse the file again?

Comment: can u provide input data and expected output

Comment: If all of your lines contain `\t` at the last apart from new line, then why don't you just use splicing. E.g. `line[:-2]+line[-1]`

Answer (score 1):

Just use a regular expression

```
>>> import re
>>> s="1\t2\t3\t\t\n"
>>> s2=re.sub('\t+\n','\n',s)
>>> s2
'1\t2\t3\n'
```

Comment: And remember to add the multiline flag

Comment: @Bhargav You're right, but I was assuming the OP would be reading the file one line at a time (as they are very new to Python).