# How to flatten the parse tree and store in a string for further string operations python nltk

Tags: python, string, parsing, tree, nltk

I am trying to get flat tree from the tree structure like the one given below.

[image: parse tree]

I want to get this whole tree in a string like without Bad tree detected error:

```
( (S (NP-SBJ (NP (DT The) (JJ high) (JJ seven-day) )(PP (IN of) (NP (DT the) (CD 400) (NNS money) )))(VP (VBD was) (NP-PRD (CD 8.12) (NN %) )(, ,) (ADVP (RB down) (PP (IN from) (NP (CD 8.14) (NN %) ))))(. .) ))
```

Comment: Why do you want to do that?   That just makes it hard to process.  Trees are easy and provide lots of structure that you have re-invent from the text.

Answer (score 5):

You can convert the tree into string using str function then split and join as follow:

```
parse_string = ' '.join(str(tree).split()) 

print parse_string
```

Answer (score 3):

Python nltk provide a function for tree manipulation and node extraction

```
from nltk.tree import Tree
for tr in trees:
    tr1 = str(tr)
    s1 = Tree.fromstring(tr1)
    s2 = s1.productions()
```

Answer (score 2):

The [documentation](http://www.nltk.org/_modules/nltk/tree.html) provides a `pprint()` method that flattens the tree into one line.

Parsing this sentence:

```
string = "My name is Ross and I am cool. What's going on world? I'm looking for friends."
```

And then calling `pprint()` yields the following:

```
u"(NP+SBAR+S\n  (S\n    (NP (PRP$ my) (NN name))\n    (VP\n      (VBZ is)\n      (NP (NNP Ross) (CC and) (PRP I) (JJ am) (NN cool.))\n      (SBAR\n        (WHNP (WP What))\n        (S+VP (VBZ 's) (VBG going) (NP (IN on) (NN world)))))\n    (. ?))\n  (S\n    (NP (PRP I))\n    (VP (VBP 'm) (VBG looking) (PP (IN for) (NP (NNS friends))))\n    (. .)))"
```

From this point, if you wish to remove the tabs and newlines, you can use the following `split` and `join` [(see here)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10711116/strip-spaces-tabs-newlines-python):

```
splitted = tree.pprint().split()
flat_tree = ' '.join(splitted)
```

Executing that yields this for me:

```
u"(NP+SBAR+S (S (NP (PRP$ my) (NN name)) (VP (VBZ is) (NP (NNP Ross) (CC and) (PRP I) (JJ am) (NN cool.)) (SBAR (WHNP (WP What)) (S+VP (VBZ 's) (VBG going) (NP (IN on) (NN world))))) (. ?)) (S (NP (PRP I)) (VP (VBP 'm) (VBG looking) (PP (IN for) (NP (NNS friends)))) (. .)))"
```

Answer (score 1):

NLTK provides functionality to do this right away:

```
flat_tree = tree._pformat_flat("", "()", False)
```

`tree.pprint()` and `str(tree)` both would call this method internally, but adding extra logic to split it into multiple lines if needed.