# Trrying to extraxt information using NLTK

Tags: python-3.x, nltk

I want to extract information from a given news, the news are text like this:

> O'Sullivan could run in Worlds
>
> Sonia O'Sullivan has indicated that she would like to participate in
> next month's World Cross Country Championships in St Etienne.
>
> Athletics Ireland have hinted that the 35-year-old Cobh runner may be
> included in the official line-up for the event in France on 19-20
> March. Provincial teams were selected after last Saturday's Nationals
> in Santry and will be officially announced this week. O'Sullivan is at
> present preparing for the London marathon on 17 April. The
> participation of O'Sullivan, currentily training at her base in
> Australia, would boost the Ireland team who won the bronze three years
> agio. The first three at Santry last Saturday, Jolene Byrne, Maria
> McCambridge and Fionnualla Britton, are automatic selections and will
> most likely form part of the long-course team. O'Sullivan will also
> take part in the Bupa Great Ireland Run on 9 April in Dublin.

I tried with this code, that extract the information of the ieer doc 'NYT_19980315'.

```
IN = re.compile(r'.*\bin\b(?!\b.+ing)')
for doc in nltk.corpus.ieer.parsed_docs('NYT_19980315'):
    for rel in nltk.sem.relextract.extract_rels('ORG', 'LOC', doc,corpus='ieer', pattern = IN):
         print (nltk.sem.relextract.rtuple(rel))
```

With this code, the output is:

```
[ORG: 'WHYY'] 'in' [LOC: 'Philadelphia']
[ORG: 'McGlashan &AMP; Sarrail'] 'firm in' [LOC: 'San Mateo']
[ORG: 'Freedom Forum'] 'in' [LOC: 'Arlington']
[ORG: 'Brookings Institution'] ', the research group in' [LOC: 'Washington']
[ORG: 'Idealab'] ', a self-described business incubator based in' [LOC: 'Los Angeles']
[ORG: 'Open Text'] ', based in' [LOC: 'Waterloo']
[ORG: 'WGBH'] 'in' [LOC: 'Boston']
[ORG: 'Bastille Opera'] 'in' [LOC: 'Paris']
[ORG: 'Omnicom'] 'in' [LOC: 'New York']
[ORG: 'DDB Needham'] 'in' [LOC: 'New York']
[ORG: 'Kaplan Thaler Group'] 'in' [LOC: 'New York']
[ORG: 'BBDO South'] 'in' [LOC: 'Atlanta']
[ORG: 'Georgia-Pacific'] 'in' [LOC: 'Atlanta']
```

The problem is that I am trying to send my text (the news that the user insert), in this case is 002.txt.
I am not able to pass the text as a parameter of the nltk.sem.extract_rels() function, it says that AttributeError: 'Tree' object has no attribute 'text', does anyone know how to do it?
Is there any way to convert the .txt to an ieer document?

The problem is that I am trying to send my text (the news that the user inserts), in this case it is 002.txt.
I am not able to pass the text as a parameter of the function nltk.sem.extract_rels(), it tells me: AttributeError: the object 'Tree' does not have the attribute 'text'.
Does anyone know how to do it? Is there any way to convert the .txt to an ieer document?

Now, I am working with this code:

```
import re
import nltk
import os

with open('002.txt', 'r') as f:
    sample = f.read()


sentences = nltk.sent_tokenize(sample)
tokenized_sentences = [nltk.word_tokenize(sentence) for sentence in sentences]
tagged_sentences = [nltk.pos_tag(sentence) for sentence in tokenized_sentences]
chunked_sentences = nltk.ne_chunk_sents(tagged_sentences, binary=True)

def extract_entity_names(t):
    entity_names = []

    if hasattr(t, 'label') and t.label:
        if t.label() == 'NE':
            entity_names.append(' '.join([child[0] for child in t]))
        else:
            for child in t:
                entity_names.extend(extract_entity_names(child))

    return entity_names


entity_names = []
for tree in chunked_sentences:    
    entity_names.extend(extract_entity_names(tree))

# Print unique entity names
print(set(entity_names))
```

The output is:

```
{'London', 'Australia', 'Worlds Sonia', 'Santry', 'Bupa Great Ireland Run', 'Maria', 'France', 'Fionnualla Britton', 'Dublin', 'Jolene Byrne', 'Ireland'}
```

And tried to add this lines [nltk.sem.extract_rels()](https://tedboy.github.io/nlps/generated/generated/nltk.sem.extract_rels.html):

```
for rel in nltk.sem.extract_rels('ORG', 'LOC', doc, corpus='ieer', pattern = IN):
    print(nltk.sem.rtuple(rel))
```

Comment: What do you mean send text?  Where do you want to send the text? Do you want to transmit to another device, output to a file, or reformat text in some special way?  It is very difficult to answer your question without seeing the data that produces your problem. Please read about how to ask a good question and try to post a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example "Minimal Reproducible Example") so we can better help you.

Comment: @itprorh66 Hi thanks for the help, I change the post trying to be more specific.
Now im using this function: nltk.sem.relextract.extract_rels(), which extracts the information from the ieer document 'NYT_19980315', which is included in the library.
I want to use the function with the news that the user inserts.
I hope i can explain myself.
Thanks again for the help ^^.

Comment: please update your question and post the entire traceback error message as code in your question/

Comment: Does this help [How to flatten the parse tree and store in a string for further string operations python nltk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28704060/how-to-flatten-the-parse-tree-and-store-in-a-string-for-further-string-operation)