# Adding a new string method in Python

Tags: python, string, function, class

I am parsing a bunch of HTML and am encountering a lot of "\n" and "\t" inside the code.  So I am using

```
"something\t\n here".replace("\t","").replace("\n","")
```

This works, but I'm using it often.  Is there a way to define a string function, along the lines of replace itself (or find, index, format, etc.) that will pretty my code a little, something like

```
"something\t\n here".noTabsOrNewlines()
```

I tried

```
class str:
    def noTabNewline(self):
        self.replace("\t","").replace("\n","")
```

but that was no good.  Thanks for any help.

Comment: you are on track with creating a class and using a method to perform your funciton.. make sure you read up on classes and objects

Comment: https://github.com/clarete/forbiddenfruit  <-- here be dragons

Comment: What about using `noTabsOrNewlines("something\t\n here")` instead?

Comment: @RyanAmos Thanks.  That'll do perfectly.  Of course now I'm still curious about how to define a method that will appear after "something".<<here>>

Comment: @BrandonMacer: You can't add methods to builtin types.

Comment: @BrenBarn My heart is broken and can only be mended with time.  But thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While you could do something along these lines (https://stackoverflow.com/a/4698550/1867876), the more Pythonic thing to do would be:

`myString = "something\t\n here"
' '.join(myString.split())`

You can see this thread for more information:
[Strip spaces/tabs/newlines - python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10711116/strip-spaces-tabs-newlines-python)

Comment: I'll take this because it's pretty and that's what I wanted, though my curiosity remains for adding methods to "something" (or [somethings] or (somethings), for that matter)

Comment: You can see this previous post at http://stackoverflow.com/a/4698550/1867876. I updated my answer to include this above.

Answer (score 1):

you can try encoding='utf-8'. otherwise in my opinion there is no other way otherthan replacing it . python also replaces it spaces with '/xa0' so in anyway you have to replace it. our you can read it line by line via (readline()) instead of just read() it .