# how to scrape nested tag elements with python

Tags: python, html, json, web-scraping

hi i would like to get some data which is on below < del> or < ins> tags but i could not find any solution for it can  anyone has idea about this scraping and is there any short way for getting those informations

this is my python code

```
  import requests
  import json
  from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
  
  header = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.9.0.7) Gecko/2009021910 Firefox/3.0.7'}
  
  base_url = "https://www.n11.com/super-firsatlar"
  
  r = requests.get(base_url,headers=header)
  
  if r.status_code == 200:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
    books = soup.find_all('li',attrs={"class":"column"})
  
    result=[]
    for book in books:
      title=book.find('h3').text
      link=base_url +book.find('a')['href']
      picture = base_url + book.find('img')['src']
  
      price = soup.find('a',attrs={"class":"ins"})
  
  
  
      single ={'title':title,'link':link,'picture':picture,'price':price}
      result.append(single)
      with open('book.json','w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
        json.dump(result ,f,indent=4,ensure_ascii=False)
  else:
    print(r.status_code)
```

```html
<div class="proDetail">
  <a href="https://test.com"class="oldPrice" title="Premium">  
      
      <del>69,00 TL</del></a>
      
  <a href="https://test.com"class="newPrice" title="Premium">
     
     <ins>14,90</ins>
       
         </a>
</div>
```

and this is my output

```
{
    "title": "Premium",
    "link": "https://test.com",
    "picture": "https://pic.gif",
    "price": null
},
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are searching for the wrong class.  First search for the class 'newPrice' to get the *a-block* with:

```
price = book.find('a', attrs={'class': 'newPrice'})
```

Then you can search inside this *a-block* for the *ins-block* like:

```
price = book.find('a', attrs={'class': 'newPrice'}).find('ins')
```

Then your result would look like:

```
<ins>14,90</ins>
```

For final result strip the html tags:

```
price = book.find('a', attrs={'class': 'newPrice'}).find('ins').text.strip()
```

Comment: i used book instead of soup  then it works thanks so much also i have one issue to  i got price side as like this "price": "189,90\n                TL" how can i delete "/n"and "spaces"

Comment: @MehmetReşatDemir Did you get past the Not JSON serializable error?

Comment: @AbrarAhmed it was no work correctly and this guy solved my error this method is more easy

Comment: @MehmetReşatDemir  I don't mean find the elements. That you can find with simply with `find('ins')` if the `tags` are unique. I meant are you able to write it to JSON? I

Comment: @MehmetReşatDemir please look into this post for deleting spaces etc. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10711116/strip-spaces-tabs-newlines-python