# Is there a way to remove extra spaces/formatting from an input?

Tags: python

I'm very new to Python and am working on some code to manipulate equations. So far, my code asks the user to input an equation. I want my code to be able to take something like "X +   1 =     2" and turn it into "x+1=2" so that the rest of my code will work, no matter the format of the entered equation.

Comment: Please update your question with the code you have tried.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Strip spaces/tabs/newlines - python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10711116/strip-spaces-tabs-newlines-python)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to strip all whitespace from string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3739909/how-to-strip-all-whitespace-from-string)

Answer (score 1):

A simple string `.replace(old, new)` followed by a `.lower()` will be sufficient.

```py
"X + 1 = 2".replace(" ", "").lower() # 'x+1=2'
"X + 1   = 2".replace(" ", "").lower() # 'x+1=2'
```

for a more thorough replacement of all white space characters and not just spaces use python's `re` module:

```py
import re 

re.sub(r'\s+', '', "X + 1   = 2").lower() # 'x+1=2'
```

Answer (score 1):

To convert to lower case and strip out any spaces use lower and replace.

```
the_input = 'X + 1 = 2'

the_output = the_input.replace(' ', '').lower()

# x+1=2
```

Comment: Don't use `input` as a variable, `input()` is a built-in function in Python.

Comment: What if the user hits the space bar twice when entering data?

Comment: @MarkMoretto doesn't matter, `str.replace(char, replacement)` replaces *all* instances of `char` with `replacement`.