# Python : UTF-8 : How to count number of words in UTF-8 string?

Tags: python, string, utf-8, hindi

I need to count number of words in UTF-8 string. ie I need to write a python function which takes "एक बार,एक कौआ, बहुत प्यासा, था" as input and returns 7 ( number of words ).

I tried regular expression "\b" as shown below. But result are inconsistent.

```
wordCntExp=re.compile(ur'\b',re.UNICODE);
sen='एक बार,एक कौआ, बहुत प्यासा, था';
print len(wordCntExp.findall(sen.decode('utf-8'))) >> 1;
12
```

Any interpretation of the above answer or any other approaches to solve the above problem are appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

try to use:

```
import re
words = re.split(ur"[\s,]+",sen, flags=re.UNICODE)
count = len(words)
```

It will split words divided by whitespaces and commas. You can add other characters into first argument that are not considered as characters belonging to a word.

[inspired by this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8928557/python-splitting-string-by-all-space-characters)

[python re documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html)

Comment: Thanks for regular expression.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know anything about your language's structure, but can't you simply count the spaces?

```
>>> len(sen.split()) + 1
7
```

note the `+ 1` because there are `n - 1` spaces. [edited to split on arbitrary length spaces - thanks @Martijn Pieters]

Comment: In which case you'd use `.split()` to split on arbitrary-width whitespace. But that won't work because in the sample sentence is one comma without trailing whitespace, which may be permissible in Hindi for all we know.

Comment: I can't depend only on spaces because, between words there can be multiple spaces.                                                  >>> sen='एक बार,एक कौआ, बहुत  प्यासा, था';
>>> len(sen.split(" "))+1
8

Answer (score 0):

Using [regex](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex):

```
>>> import regex
>>> sen = 'एक बार,एक कौआ, बहुत प्यासा, था'
>>> regex.findall(ur'\w+', sen.decode('utf-8'))
[u'\u090f\u0915', u'\u092c\u093e\u0930', u'\u090f\u0915', u'\u0915\u094c\u0906', u'\u092c\u0939\u0941\u0924', u'\u092a\u094d\u092f\u093e\u0938\u093e', u'\u0925\u093e']
>>> len(regex.findall(ur'\w+', sen.decode('utf-8')))
7
```